# WKWebview Observer

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Im trying to add an observer for when my WKWebview is loading/loaded, but it only fires when it's loaded. It never fires "while" loading. What am I doing wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url:url)
        self.webView.load(request)
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading"{
            if webView.isLoading{
                print("loading")
            }
            else{
                print("done")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're starting the request, before adding the observer. Also why not use WKNavigationDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add observe *before* any operations with web view and key path in KVO is string, like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isLoading", 
                                 options: [.new], context: nil)

        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url:url)
        self.webView.load(request)
    }

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "isLoading"{
        if webView.isLoading{
            print("loading")
        }
        else{
            print("done")
        }
    }
}
```